# $T:M_5(R)$ to $M_5(R)$ be defined as $T(A)= A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

$T:M_{5}$ to $M_5(R)$ defined by $T(A)=A^T$. Let $M$ be the matrix representation with respect to the $B$ standard basis then choose the correct statement .

a) $\lambda = \{-1,1\}$ are the only eigenvalues.

b) There exist non-zero vectors $x,y  \in M_n(R)$ such that $M(x+y)=x-y$.

c) $det(M)=1$

d) Dimension $E_{lambda=-1}$ is 10

I have tried to solve this

here $T(A)=A^T$ then $T(T(A)=A$ i.e $T^2=I$ then we can say the minimal polynomial should devide $x^2-1$ . Here the possible Eigen values 1,-1 .

In (b) there exist non zero vectors $x,y \in M_n(R)$ such that $M(x+y)=x-y $
$M(x+y)= x-y $
$x^T+y^T= x-y$
$y+y^T=x-x^T$
Here left side symmetric and right side skew symmetric . Then the only possible case O matrix .
If $x-x^T=0$
$x=x^T$  i.e X is a symmetric matrix and similarly y is a skew symmetric matrix . If we choose such type of matrices then b should be true .

Can I directly find the AM of $\lambda$=-1

Comment: You should also use LaTeX to format the math in your post. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for LaTeX help and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for how to write a good post.

Comment: T(A)=A^T then T^2=I . Then the minimal polynomial devides (x^2-1) . Then the Eigen values 1,-1 only . Then option A is true .

Comment: Btw I suspect the intended assignment isn't "show which of these statements is true", but instead "prove all four of these statements". In other words, this isn't multiple choice - it's just a multi-part problem.

Comment: Add whatever you have tried.

Comment: @Nikhil It's good that you described your attempt so far, but you should also [edit] your post and add this description in.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers for (a) and (b) look good. Upvoted for editing in better context in response to the feedback :)

For the remaining parts, you'll want to figure out exactly how many eigenvalues of $1$ vs $-1$ are present. You've already figured out that symmetric matrices are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$ and skew-symmetric matrices are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-1$. So now the question is just: how many different linearly independent symmetric $5 \times 5$ matrices can you find? (And same question for skew-symmetric.) The total dimension of the vector space is $25$, so you want (number of l.i. symmetric matrices you come up with) + (number of l.i. skew symmetric matrices you come up with) = 25. Once you've done that, it should be pretty easy to solve (c) and (d).